# Firefox displays box with x in it when using font-variant: small caps & text-transform: capitalize

Tags: css, firefox, text, fonts

Firefox displays box with x in it when using

```
{
  font-variant: small caps;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Firefox IMG Screenshot:

[image]

This is how it should look:

Google Chrome IMG Screenshot

[image]

The font-family is: `"Requiem Text A", "Requiem Text B", Cambria, "Hoefler Text", Utopia, "Liberation Serif", "Nimbus Roman No9 L Regular", Times, "Times New Roman", serif`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'm noticing is that font-variant: small caps should be "small-caps". http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-variant.asp

Comment: Well spotted, but that by itself can't cause the differences in the OP's screenshots. `small caps` doesn't do anything in any browser.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it doesn't do anything. :(